# Getting Error(42,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" on PlSQL code.

Tags: plsql

Using sql developer.  I am a newbie to PLSQl.  I have tried a lot of the solutions that have been suggested and a bunch that have not been suggested. Seems like I either get the "end" or "Begin" PLS-00103 error.  Below is the code.  Thanks in advance for any help - greatly appreciate it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1 
(
       category_id in Messages.category_id%type,
       messagetext in Messages.messagetext%type,
       lastupdatedBy in Messages.lastupdatedBy%type,
       message_id out Messages.message_id%type,
       txtcomment out varchar2)
as
BEGIN
  Declare  uniquecategoryid number := 0;
  uniquemsgid number := 0;
    BEGIN
        -- verify that category id is a valid category
     SELECT Categories.category_id 
           INTO uniquecategoryid 
           FROM Categories
           WHERE  Categories.category_id = PROCEDURE1.category_id;
    EXCEPTION     
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
     uniquecategoryid := 0;
    END;

     BEGIN   
      SELECT message_id into uniquemsgid
            FROM Messages
            where Messages.messagetext = PROCEDURE1.messagetext
            AND uniquecategoryid > 0;
     EXCEPTION     
       WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       uniquecategoryid := 0;
    END;      

     Begin   
      INSERT INTO Messages (CATEGORY_ID, messagetext, lastupdatedby, lastupdated, status)
            VALUES (PROCEDURE1.category_id, PROCEDURE1.messagetext,
                  PROCEDURE1.lastupdatedBy, SYSDATE,'A')
            returning Messages.message_id INTO PROCEDURE1.message_id;
      COMMIT;
      PROCEDURE1.txtcomment := 'SUCCESS';
    end;
END;    
END PROCEDURE1;
```

Comment: **remove second last line:** `END;`

Comment: Using a text editor - count the `BEGIN` statements, then count the `END` statements and you'll find it (since you don't have `IF` or `CASE` etc. statements).

Comment: Btw, you'll also get an error on the `Declare` statement, as named pl/sql Procedures of Functions don't use that. Their "Declare" sections is just above the first `BEGIN~ of the corresponding unit.

Comment: Thanks so much! - this worked!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the **END;** stated above END PROCEDURE1;. The code understands the end of procedure block by END PROCEDURE1;. END; is useless in this case.